# How can I report progress based on multiple variables in a nested loop (for a progress bar)?

Tags: c#, math, logic, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I have a BackgroundWorker and a single ProgressBar. When working, the BackgroundWorker runs through a triple for-loop and reports progress to the ProgressBar.

Currently, the progress that is being reported is only that of the outter-most loop (xProgress), which works, but does not run smoothly. The goal is for the ProgressBar to also account for the progress percentages of the inner loops, so that the ProgressBar updates more smoothly and more accurately.

The DoWork method:

```cs
    private void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        int xMax, yMax, zMax;

        xMax = 10;
        for (int x = 1; x <= xMax; x++)
        {
            yMax = 5;
            for (int y = 1; y <= yMax; y++)
            {
                zMax = new Random().Next(50, 100);
                for (int z = 1; z <= zMax; z++)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(5); /// The process

                    double xProgress = (double)x / (double)xMax;
                    double yProgress = (double)y / (double)yMax;
                    double zProgress = (double)z / (double)zMax;

                    /// The progress calculation:
                    double progressCalc = xProgress;

                    int progress = (int)(progressCalc * pgb.Maximum);

                    bgw.ReportProgress(progress);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: When a `y-loop` is at 100%, you are about to increase `x` by 1, so you could say the `100% y` is a `1% x`, and same for z and y. So `var prog = xProg + yProg*0.01d*xMax + zProg*0.01d*yMax*0.01d*xMax` (or *something like that*). You *might* have to get the loops going from 0 to `max-1` instead of 1 to `max` for it to calculate correctly, but I'm not sure, you should check it.

Comment: Unfortunately, setting `progressCalc` to that formula caused the end result to exceed 1.00d, which caused the ProgressBar to overflow.

Comment: I did tell you you should check it. Are you going from 0 to max-1?

Comment: After changing the bounds, the ProgressBar still overflows with that formula.

Comment: Yeah that was silly of me. See answer for correct way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works even if you don't know your best/worst case in advance.
Any of the max's could be randomized in the same fashion of `zMax`.

```
static void F()
{
    var r = new Random();
    int xMax = 10;
    int yMax = 5;
    int zMax;

    for (int x = 0; x < xMax; x++)
    {
        double xProg = (double)x / xMax;

        for (int y = 0; y < yMax; y++)
        {
            double yProg = (double)y / (yMax * xMax);

            zMax = r.Next(50, 100);
            for (int z = 0; z < zMax; z++)
            {
                double zProg = (double)z / (zMax * yMax * xMax);

                var prog = xProg + yProg + zProg;

                Console.WriteLine(prog.ToString("P"));
                // bgw.ReportProgress((int)(prog * pgb.Maximum));
            }
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(1.ToString("P")); // Make sure to report the final 100%
    // bgw.ReportProgress((int)pgb.Maximum);
}
```

Btw, I'd replace the `pgb.Maximum`'s with `1` and in the `OnProgressHandler` multiply the progress by it. That way the threaded method does not touch UI elements at all.

Answer (score 3):

It's true that you can't know exactly how many iterations your loops will do, but you certainly can smooth your progress indicator.

Let's assume your total iterations in the worst case is xMax * yMax * worstZMax.

worstZMax = 99 because the upper bound is exclusive in `Random.Next(minValue:int, maxValue:int)`

Hence the total iterations in worst case scenario will be `5 * 10 * 99 = 4950`.

Now we could start with that total and adjust it as required when we loose iterations after generating zMax for each y loop and we'll effectively smooth the progress calculation and reporting.

This is how I'd do it:

```
private void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    const int xMax = 10;
    const int yMax = 5;
    const int worstZMax = 99; //because upper is exclusive in Random.Next(lower, upper) 

    var iteration = 0;
    var total = xMax * yMax * worstZMax; //total number of iterations (worst case)

    for (var x = 1; x <= xMax; x++)
    {
        for (var y = 1; y <= yMax; y++)
        {
            var zMax = new Random().Next(50, 100);

            //get how many iterations did we miss, and adjust the total iterations
            total -= worstZMax - zMax;
            for (var z = 1; z <= zMax; z++)
            {
                iteration++;  //count this iteration
                Thread.Sleep(5); // The process

                // The progress calculation
                var progress = (double)iteration / total * pgb.Maximum;

                bgw.ReportProgress((int)progress);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Updated Answer:

Since inner loop has unknown number of iterations you could decide how many steps it should advance. for example 10.

Then you could do something like this:

```
progressbarMaximum = xMax * yMax * 10
```

right before z-loop you get the zModulo by dividing zMax with 10.
in your z-loop check if

```
zMax % zModulo == 0
```

then increment progressbar.

Old answer:

If you multiply xMax, yMax and zMax you get the total number of iterations of the innermost loop.

Set progressbar maximum to that value.

On each iteration of the inner loop increment progressbar.

Comment: Unfortunately, as shown in the code, zMax changes for each y. So, I don't know the total number of iterations going in.

Answer (score 0):

You *can't* make it exact. Think of it this way - what if the first randoms were all 50 and you have already done half of the 2 outer loops - if the rest of the randoms will be 50 - you've done 50%. If the rest of the randoms will be 100 - you will only have done 33%. So you don't know how far the progress bar should be.

(Of course random results won't usually be like that. It's just to illustrate the point.)